# GARCH hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, garch

I am trying to test for GARCH effects. However, I don't understand what the null hypothesis is and how it works. I refer to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity) Wikipedia article about ARCH and GARCH models.

In the ARCH-LM test (Engle, 1982) it seems clear what we have to do.
For example, if I want to test for an ARCH(6) I just need to use an $F$-test and put $H_0$: $\alpha_1=...=\alpha_6=0$.

Now, seeing how the GARCH model is specified, we have $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ coefficients with $i=1,\dotsc,q$ and $j=1,\dotsc,p$.
So I would expect to do another $F$-test, for example in a GARCH(3,3) I would test for $H_0: \alpha_1=\dotsb=\alpha_3=0$ and $\beta_1=\dotsb=\beta_3=0$

However it's unclear to me what is the test done in Wikipedia and how it is called (when he talks about model specification).

Comment: Could you name precisely what tests are you considering, and give relevant references? The ARCH-LM test is described in Engle's original 1982 paper where he introduced the ARCH model; the paper is quite readable, if I remember correctly. It should also be found in time series textbooks covering GARCH models. But for starters let's find out what you really are after. What exactly are your hypotheses of interest? (In a sense, it is unclear whether you have a hypothesis and need help designing a relevant test; or you have a test and want to find out how it actually works.)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I rewrote my question, hope it's ok now.

Comment: Do you mean the description of using Ljung-Box statistic in stage 3. of GARCH model specification? Is step 3. there unclear?

Comment: Step 2 is also unclear, why it's calculating the autocorrelations? Is this equivalent to put all the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to zero? Maybe I understood what is the problem, is this test testing for arch vs garch? because I want to test no arch and/or no garch against garch

Comment: I edited your post a bit; you may roll-back if you don't like it. I will need to come back to the question tomorrow, do not have more time today. Or maybe someone else will answer it.